# Как исправить проблему SSL?

Tags: nginx, ssl

На сайте site.ru ранее был другoy сертификат, недавнo пoмeняли на другой серт от другой компании, теперь на некотрых устройствах ресурс открывается а на некоторых не пишет err_cert_invaldid_name те стоит старый серт. Как со стороны нжинкс заставить для этих же обновить серт?

Comment: Максимально неинформативное описание проблемы

Answer (score 0):

Две директивы `ssl_certificate` и `ssl_certificate_key` в Nginx отвечают за путь к файлу сертификата и ключу.

Проверьте пути и перечитайте конфиг Nginx командой `nginx -s reload`

Comment: пути указаны правильно, единственное для некоторых девайсов сертификат открывается старый а для большинства сертификат новый, попробовали на одном устройстве андроид почистить кеш и открыть всё равно показывается в деталях подключения сертификат от другой компании